# How to get real signature with %ROWTYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to get the real signature for a PLSQL procedure which uses %ROWTYPE arguments ?

For example :

```
clear screen;
prompt > Table creation to support %ROWTYPE
create table samples (
  id number,
  code varchar2(15),
  lib varchar2(200) );

prompt > Package witch use %ROWTYPE
create or replace package use_samples as
  procedure getSample(input_sample samples%ROWTYPE);
end use_samples;
/
prompt > Package BODY witch use %ROWTYPE
create or replace package body use_samples as
  procedure getSample(input_sample IN samples%ROWTYPE) is
    ex samples%ROWTYPE;
  begin
    select * into ex from samples where samples.code = input_sample.code;
  end getSample;
end use_samples;
/

prompt > Proc arguments by ALL_ARGUMENTS
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 2000
set verify off
CLEAR COLUMNS;
COLUMN object_name HEADING "PROC" FORMAT A30 JUSTIFY LEFT;
COLUMN argument_name HEADING "ARGUMENT_NAME" FORMAT A30 JUSTIFY LEFT;

select object_name, argument_name, in_out, data_level, position, data_type
from all_arguments
where owner = USER
and package_name = 'USE_SAMPLES'
and object_name = 'GETSAMPLE';

prompt >> Argument 'INPUT_SAMPLE' is shown as 'PL/SQL RECORD' without any link to 'samples%ROWTYPE'

prompt > PLSQL types declared
select *
from DBA_PLSQL_TYPES
where owner = USER
and package_name = 'USE_SAMPLES';

prompt >> There is no declared type because we use directly a %ROWTYPE argument


prompt > Clean up  
drop package use_samples;
drop table samples;
```

gives :

```
> Table creation to support %ROWTYPE

Table SAMPLES created.

> Package witch use %ROWTYPE

Package USE_SAMPLES compiled

> Package BODY witch use %ROWTYPE

Package body USE_SAMPLES compiled
> Proc arguments by ALL_ARGUMENTS
columns cleared

PROC                           ARGUMENT_NAME                  IN_OUT    DATA_LEVEL   POSITION DATA_TYPE                    
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
GETSAMPLE                      INPUT_SAMPLE                   IN                 0          1 PL/SQL RECORD                 
GETSAMPLE                      ID                             IN                 1          1 NUMBER                        
GETSAMPLE                      CODE                           IN                 1          2 VARCHAR2                      
GETSAMPLE                      LIB                            IN                 1          3 VARCHAR2                      

>> Argument 'INPUT_SAMPLE' is shown as 'PL/SQL RECORD' without any link to 'samples%ROWTYPE'
> PLSQL types declared
no rows selected


>> There is no declared type because we use directly a %ROWTYPE argument
> Clean up

Package USE_SAMPLES dropped.


Table SAMPLES dropped.
```

So with ALL_ARGUMENTS, 'INPUT_SAMPLE' is shown as 'PL/SQL RECORD' without any link to 'samples%ROWTYPE'. And there is no trace of this type in DBA_PLSQL_TYPES.

How can I get the declared type of this procedure under this form ?

```
GETSAMPLE  INPUT_SAMPLE IN  SAMPLES%ROWTYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to go other way round:

1) create object type with all attributes you need in your table

2) create object table of your TYPE

3) pass argument into you procedure of your TYPE

4) you can get type name from all_arguments

`%rowtype` and `%type` are pseudo-types dynamically resolved during compilation. So what would you expect to see in data_dictionary info in this case? There is no named record/type/object related to sample%rowtype.

Comment: Not directly related to this answer, but check the URL on your profile.  It looks like that website is being hijacked.  I get forwarded to spammy sites when I visit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched in dictionary and found nothing. If there is no info (I don't know), you can use something like:

```
SELECT b.object_name,b.argument_name, REGEXP_SUBSTR (UPPER (text),'([^{ ,(;}]+)%ROWTYPE') tadaaa
  FROM user_source a
       JOIN (SELECT package_name, object_name, argument_name, in_out, data_level, position, data_type
               FROM user_arguments x
              WHERE data_type = 'PL/SQL RECORD' AND package_name = 'USE_SAMPLES' AND object_name = 'GETSAMPLE' ) b
          ON a.name = b.package_name
 WHERE a.TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY' 
   AND UPPER (text) LIKE '%\%ROWTYPE%' ESCAPE '\'
   AND UPPER (text) LIKE '%'||UPPER(ARGUMENT_NAME)||'%'
```

:) Let some guru in regex check my regex expression. Actually the argument name have to be in regex too.

Comment: i suppose, this idea will work if all packages will work in concrete style. In other case, we can not support all possible options

Comment: I wouldn't put it actually as answer, but the code look awful in comments.

Comment: This really only ever works for the simplest use-cases. E.g. 1) the `%ROWTYPE` operator can be put on a new line, 2) the table could be a synonym / fully qualified from another schema, 3) the `%ROWTYPE` could be a nested `RECORD` type in another `RECORD`, etc.